# Improve rendering quality in directx 9

Tags: windows, direct3d

I have a direct3d9 application which can render camera output onto a window. What are the things I should consider to improve the rendering video quality in direct3d 9 ?

Comment: Your question needs to be more detailed and specific to be answerable here.

Comment: I just wanted to know, is there any pre-processing methods available in direct3d to present the video with highest quality ?

Comment: There aren't any pre-processing methods available in Direct3D. If you want your video processed you have to provide the code that does the processing.